# Can dual booting be done with the minimal CD?

Tags: system-installation

I'm wanting to keep Ubuntu alongside Windows, can you do that is you use the minimal install CD?

Answer (score 0):

You can dual-boot with any of the installation CD/DVD/USB Drives. The guided install with the visual installer makes life a bit easier for the inexperienced in having a "install alongside Windows" option that helps you do this, but it's not very tricky in either, especially if you've already got space set aside for the Ubuntu install.

Comment: I'm only using a minimal because I don't have a DVD or USB drive, but as long as you can choose to install to replace or alongside another OS, then I'm fine with it.

Comment: If you can set the space aside from within Windows then it's even more likely to go well. The place where you can most easily have bad luck is in resizing partitions; generally works safely, but it can go wrong. Backup your data and have a Windows install CD to hand for the worse case scenario.